# What is the difference between a $1\times 1$ matrix and a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to find the eigen pairs of  $aa^T$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I solved the problem in the following manner-

$$aa^Tx=\lambda x \ (\lambda \neq 0)$$
$$ x = \beta a \ (\beta \neq 0)\ \implies \beta a^Ta=\beta \lambda $$
$$\lambda = a^Ta$$

$aa^T$ is rank $1$ matrix, so the other eigen values are $0$ and corresponding eigen-vectors will be orthogonal to $a$.

But there is a subtle part which always intriguing me. $a^Ta$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix then how we can equate with a scalar quantity.

So, my main question is what is the difference between a $1\times 1$ matrix and a scalar?

Any insight is appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: a scalar *is* a $1\times 1$ matrix. Notice, you should exclude $a=0$.

Comment: Yes that is true. Okay, let say if $1 \times 1$ matrix is same as scalar, then $1 \times 1$ matrix multiplying with a $n \times m \ (n \neq 1)$ is not valid but the scalar-matrix multiplication is valid.

Comment: Sure. ${}{}{}{}$